# Why I can't link to Node.js in Mathematica

Tags: external-calls, javascript

Suddenly I want to use `ExternalEvaluate` with Mathematica(for windows 10@12.0/12.1) and Node.js(for windows 10@12.14.1 and zeromq@5.2.0). Sure I have already read the help named `workflow/ConfigureNodeJSForExternalEvaluate`, but it still doesn't work.

```
StartExternalSession::replFail: The process for external system NodeJS \
(C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe) failed to start due to:\
no input returned from process. For help configuring the NodeJS evaluator,\
see  Configure NodeJS for ExternalEvaluate.
```

Comment: Can you share the exact code you tried at least?

Comment: It's `FindExternalEvaluators["NodeJS"]`, and it returned `MissingDependencies`.